# Play Media in JSPX ADF?

Tags: java, html, plugins, wav, oracle-adf

Dears ,

I have been trying to get the ADF page to play audio files that is stored on the server with extension "wav" , am facing a problem that when I use `<af:media>`

following the link details/Instructions :

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24001_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_media.html

the result so far , I managed to get the path using managed bean I provided it as a source using page flow scope

```
<af:media source="#{pageFlowScope.filePath}" standbyText="Play Recording" id="m3"/>
```

the filePath would look like this : `/recording/2018/11/07/test.wav`

but the result on Chrome is like this :

[image]

here is the element inspected :

```
<embed width="275" height="40" name="pt1:pc1:m3" type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" autostart="0" src="/TestWebApp-ViewController-context-root/recording/2018/11/07/test.wav">
```

so I am wondering if someone has tried this before

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue by using audio html5 , and the managed bean provide the file in base64 using common-codec library

```
 private String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName)
                            throws IOException {

            File file = new File(convert(fileName));
            byte[] bytes = loadFile(file);
            byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
            String encodedString = new String(encoded);

            return "data:audio/mpeg;base64,"+encodedString;
    }

    private static byte[] loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        long length = file.length();
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            // File is too large
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];

        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }

        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file "+file.getName());
        }

        is.close();
        return bytes;
    }
```

and I invoked the above method given the path and store it in pageFlowScope

jspx part :

```
<audio src="${pageFlowScope.filePath}" controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload"></audio>
```

Regards,